# increasing training error, stable validation error in deep learning

Tags: deep-learning

I am training data which has almost 1 million training set, 1 million validation set, and 1 million test set.

As I monitor the log, I see that when validation error is stable, training error is increasing.

Am I on the right path, or what should I do in this case?

Thanks,

Comment: What software do you use for training? What type of netwok you use? What is your parameters? Dimension of input data? It looks like your test and validation set are too huge. Probably it should have ratio 0.6 for training, and 0.2 for test and 0.2 for validarion.

Comment: It would be very useful if you share the graph you monitor.